# Use git client to pull and push from/to hg server

Tags: git, mercurial

I'd like to be able to use git to work with a hg server.  I guess it's possible, but couldn't find how.  I've found help for doing the reverse (hg client and git server).

I'm using Debian Sid.

How can I do this, ideally transparently through the git(1) command (using a plugin), or if not possible, using some external command that takes my git repo and pushes/pulls from it?

Comment: https://github.com/dusty-phillips/gitifyhg/wiki/List-of-git-hg-bridges Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bmercurial%5D+migrate

Comment: https://github.com/felipec/git/wiki/Comparison-of-git-remote-hg-alternatives

Comment: Through the first of your links, I found that [`git-remote-hg(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-remote-hg/git-remote-hg.1.en.html), maintained inside `git` (but in Debian you need to install a separate package [`git-remote-hg`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/git-remote-hg)) is probably the best thing.  I'll try it out tomorrow or so, and will come back here with some review.  Thanks!